# hover over and each

Tags: jquery-hover, jquery

I want the user to hover over a a link which has a class called picture and the span to animate (increase the padding top), here is the code I have made so far but when the user hovers over it, it animates them all, i only want it to animate the one the user has hovered over.

```
$('.picture').each(function(){
    $('.picture').hover(function(){
        $('.picture span').animate({
            'padding-top' : '20px'
        },'fast');
    });

    $('.picture').mouseout(function(){
        $('.picture span').animate({
            'padding-top' : '10px'
        },'fast');
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated I think its somewhere on the each function Im going wrong but am unsure. A link to it can be found here: http://bathroomsyork.co.uk/

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any benefit of your outer `each()` call.  You should try this:

```
$('.picture').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('span').animate({'padding-top' : '20px'},'fast');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('span').animate({'padding-top' : '10px'},'fast');
    }
);
```

Note that we select all picture class elements, then use both parameters of the `hover()` function to specify `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event callbacks.

Within each callback, get the child spans of the currently hovered element, `$(this)`, and perform the animation.

Comment: For some reason all spans are still padded together: http://jsfiddle.net/xrUJn/ It looks like something else influencing this on the site.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I actually just noted from your fiddle that the `span` is not a direct child of `.picture` so I changed this to `find()`, but I am still having a problem in your fiddle with that working.  I have absolutely no idea why, as this should absolutely work.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl It is super hacky, but I was able to get this to work by specifying id of the individual ids of the `<a>` tags inside the picture divs.  See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xrUJn/4/

Comment: Seems the fiddle was messed up and the OP script included conflicted with the jQuery included in the fiddle itself. Alexander notice this. Never dawned on me. +1 on your answer as it works now ones the  references are removed from the fiddle and only use OPs references in the HTML. Silly really I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to iterate over all elements, you can bind the event handler to all the matched elements at the same time.

Also, use `$('span', this)` to select the correct `<span>` from the hovered element.

```
$('.picture').on({
  mouseenter: function () {
    $('span', this).animate({
      'padding-top': '20px'
    }, 'fast');
  },
  mouseout: function () {
    $('span', this).animate({
      'padding-top': '10px'
    }, 'fast');
  }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle, HTML copy-pasted from OP linked website: http://jsfiddle.net/he4aM/ Even with your code which makes sense it still applies padding to all of the spans which is strange.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, actually. It is working. But, you were including the OP's own script along with the page. A conflict was generated by doing this

Comment: +1 Nice one, it worked now. I had the fiddle references removed but never saved it when I copied the links to the comments. Rather silly. Well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

this worked in the end guys:

```
$('.picture').each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $('span', this).animate({
            'padding-top' : '20px'
        },'fast');
    }, function(){
        $('span', this).animate({
            'padding-top' : '10px'
        },'fast');
    });
});
```

When I tried the examples with the on() i got a console error, what does that do exactly as I haven't seen that before?

thanks anyway.

Comment: You are using jQuery 1.6 and `.on()` is available as of jQuery 1.7. That's why

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `each`.

```
$('.picture').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    var padding = e.type == 'mouseenter' ? '20px' : '10px';
    $('span', this).animate({
        'padding-top' : padding
    },'fast');
});
```

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski It was fixed before your comment :)